# Getting latest Records in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a django project. In this project I am getting updates in database every 2 seconds. How can apply filter in QuerySet so that I can get records updated in last 2 second in database? And if there is no update in last 2 seconds it should not return anything.

Comment: did you try something on which we could argue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `DatetimeField` with `auto_now_add=True` you can try:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(
    fieldname__gte=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(seconds=2)
)
```

[update]

> what is fielname_gte, I need all object updated i last 2 seconds –  user2244344

**IF** you have a `DatetimeField` with `auto_now_add=True` fielname (sic) **IS** the name of that field, note that there are two underscores - `__gte` means "greater than or equal".

BTW it is potentially harmful to pound your database like this (especially if there is a lot of traffic). Memchached or Redis are better for this kind of pooling.

Comment: what is fielname_gte, I need all object updated i last 2 seconds